Expectation under convex order
I am trying to understand if the following statement is true. Let $M,N$ and $X$ be random variables. If the following inequality holds for any concave non-decreasing function $u$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[u(N)]\leq\mathbb{E}[u(M)]
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[u(N+X)]\leq\mathbb{E}[u(M+X)]
\end{equation}
Note that there is no an assumed relation between $N$ and $M$.

While this isn't true, I suspect it might be true if $X$ is independent of $(M,N)$.

Do you think that it could be true only if I restrict $X$ to be a constant, or at least a nonnegative r.v.?

There shouldn't be any need to make $X$ non-negative, because you don't know if $M$ and $N$ are positive or negative.  It reminds me of what Pollard calls Anderson's Lemma, which is specialised to  $N=0$  and symmetric $M$

I get it. Thank you very much for your answers. I will learn more about Anderson's Lemma.

The implication does not hold.
For example, let $M \equiv 0$, $N$ be the Radamacher random variable (i.e., $P(N = \pm 1) = \frac{1}{2}$). Then for any concave function $u$, it follows by Jensen's inequality that
\begin{align*}
E[u(N)] \leq u(E(N)) = u(0) = u(M) = E[u(M)].
\end{align*}
On the other hand, for $X = -2N$, we have
\begin{align*}
& E[u(N + X)] = E[u(-N)] = \frac{1}{2}u(1) + \frac{1}{2}u(-1), \\
& E[u(M + X)] = E[u(-2N)] = \frac{1}{2}u(2) + \frac{1}{2}u(-2). 
\end{align*}
Obviously, $u(1) + u(-1) \leq u(2) + u(-2)$ cannot hold for any concave and non-decreasing function $u$.  For example, it cannot hold for
\begin{align*}
u(x) = (x + 1)I_{(-\infty, 0)}(x) + I_{[0, \infty)}(x), 
\end{align*}
for which $u(1) + u(-1) = 1 + 0 = 1 > u(2) + u(-2) = 1 + (-1) = 0$.

Thank you very much for your answer. I have some comments, $u(x)=x$ is a concave non-decreasing function for which the inequality holds. Do you think that the statement could be true if $X$ is restricted to be nonnegative r.v. or maybe for a constant?.

Or maybe conditions for $M$ and $N$? Actually I am looking for conditions under the statement is true. Thank you very much again.
